# Walk around for assigning attributes dynamically to ViewModel in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have ViewModel that is closely related to BLL model. So now I have:

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
}
```

It is displayed on page as simple panel:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-content">
    <form method="post" class="col s12" id="sim_house_seeker">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Colour)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Colour )
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">credit_card</i>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MaximalPrice)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.MaximalPrice)
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Save</button>
    </form>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

Now I would like to be able to use that ViewModel do display another data, so I would like to do this:

```
public class PanelViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string LeftSideOfPanel { get; set; }
    public int RightSideOfPanel { get; set; }
}
```

And ViewModel:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-content">
    <form method="post" class="col s12" id="sim_house_seeker">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">phone</i>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LeftSideOfPanel )
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.LeftSideOfPanel )
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">credit_card</i>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RightSideOfPanel )
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RightSideOfPanel )
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Save</button>
    </form>
    <div class="clearBoth"></div>
</div>
```

This gives my ability to use that panel in any model that I want to and it separates ViewModel from BLL entity. But my problem is that I add validation attributes to my ViewModel that can be different in models. I know that it is not possible to add attributes dynamically so what is the best walkaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

View Models are more closely tied to views as compared to business layer, you can create panelviewmodel interface and then viewmodels with validations accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Validation attributes are nice in a sense that the model state is updated automatically upon binding, note however that they are completely optional. Instead of relying on auto validation, you can perform validation on your own, each time based on different rules.

Down the pipeline this is completely equivalent - your views will show model errors regardless of how errors are added (by auto validation based on attributes or based on manual validatiin based on whatever you want).

What I suggest then is that instead of trying to assign validation attributes dynamically, just skip this and have your own validation code that add errors just like the attribute-based engine would add them automatically:

```
public ActionResult Foo( YourModel model )
{
    // manual validation
    if ( ... )
       ModelState.AddModelError( key, error );

    if ( ModelState.IsValid ) // this works too
       ...
```

where `key`s will refer to your model properties.